# Lower bound smallest eigenvalue of matrix product

Tags: matrices, inequality, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ and $B$ be $n \times n$ invertible matrices. Is it true that

$
\lambda_{\min}( [A \, B]'[A \, B]) ) = \lambda_{\min}( [A'A + B'B + A'B + B'A]) ) > \lambda_{\min}(A'A)?
$

Here $\lambda_{\min}(M)$ denotes the smallest eigenvalue of matrix $M.$

Comment: What if $B=-A$?

Comment: ouch! very true! :) thanks